# How to insert jquery value in php array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one upload button to upload multiple files and each time i select file then jquery onchange is called and i can set only one value to hidden input  .My question is how i can store all file names in hidden input value so i can store all file name in database.

```
<input type="hidden" name="croppedDocumentActivity[]" id="croppedDocumentActivity" value="" visibility="hidden">



     $('#activityAddOrEditFile').on('change', function(){ 
   var file = $("#activityAddOrEditFile")[0].files[0];
                var fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif','pdf','docx'];

                        var a = new Array();
                        a.push(file.name); 

                        $('#croppedDocumentActivity').val(a);


            })
```

Comment: you will get the file names when you upload the files. why do you need them before that?

Comment: Here's an idea: `<form action=".." enctype="multipart/form-data">` - Wow! It's amazing! Multiple files at once!

Comment: @nogad.i am using button not input type file

Answer (score 0):

On your script, you can just call a function that will append a new hidden element inside the form. So when you submit the form, all of the newly added elements will be passed at the same time. Try something like this.

```
$('#activityAddOrEditFile').on('change', function(){ 
   var file = $("#activityAddOrEditFile")[0].files[0];  
   appendSomething(file.name); //appends new hidden element
})


public function appendSomething(filename) { 
   $('#yourform').append('<input type="hidden" name="croppedDocumentActivity[]" value='+filename+'>'); 
}
```

Comment: @E Aia.if use your method then i get empty array in php side .that i have already tried